# Until something happens

Tags: vocabulary

Given a repeat inspection has to be done until new part will be procured, is it right to say:
"Do the recurring inspection until new parts will be delivered"

Comment: This sounds familiar... is the new part replacing the one that cracked in the defective area? :)  I see you've taken Jay's advice of using *recurring* instead of *recurrent*, which is an improvement, but something about the verb **do** being used *together* with "recurring" still doesn't sound exactly right. Instead of "Do the recurring inspection," what about something like "Carry out the inspection at regular (or maybe "scheduled"?) intervals"?

Comment: Or even just "**Carry out** the recurring inspection until new parts **are** delivered." It's just the word "Do" that makes the whole sentence sound awkward (in the original version). Also, I believe "**are** delivered" is more idiomatic than "**will be** delivered."

Comment: The event you're referring to (the delivery of new parts) is set in the future, but the word "until" already denotes future time, so it would be redundant to also use "will be."

Answer (score 1):

"Do" is a vague word. We'd probably say "conduct" or "perform".

"... until parts will be delivered" You should use the present tense, "until parts are delivered". The word "until" sets the time under discussion to when the parts are delivered, so at that point it becomes present tense.

I'd say "replacement parts" rather than "new parts" to make clear that this is replacing damaged parts and not an upgrade, which I think is what you mean. But "new parts" is correct.

There should be an article "the" before "new parts" (or "replacement parts"). We're talking about a specific set of parts, the new parts to replace the damaged ones, not just any parts. If you were going to conduct inspections until any parts arrived, regardless of what machine they were for or what their purpose was, then you would not say "the". That seems pretty unlikely, but I could imagine someone saying, for example, "We will continue to use the parts we have until new parts arrive" -- if you weren't talking about specific new parts but any new parts.

So  I'd say, "Conduct the recurring inspection until the replacement parts are delivered."